# Let users access controllers on base of role/permission in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, schema

i am trying to build application in which there will be some groups

> Super Admin, Moderators, Tenants, Users

In order that Super Admin will have access to all the pages/views and controllers. But the rest of the groups will have access to pages/views on based of roles/permissions.

I however made the main menus populated on the basis of the user groups, but problem I am facing is that if user logs in and directly access to the page with the link, the page opens, as there is no restriction on the Controller.

In other words, I need to restrict non-authenticated users from opening the restricted page/View.

I can see two ways:

1. Put restriction on every controller by putting a check if user is allowed to view that controller. But this will be tedious work and I am not sure if it's the right way.
2. Put a main check in `MY_Controller` that runs every time when controller is accessed, This looks promising but I am not sure how to accomplish this.

What is the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

What I have done in my own application is extend the core controller class using MY_Controller and inside there I have created two functions for my two user groups. Then when creating a normal controller you extend it by the user function. For example:

MY_Controller.php

```
class Super_admin extends CI_Controller{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__contstruct();
        //check for super admin privlidges
    }
}
```

some_controller.php

```
class some_controller extends Super_admin{
    //do whatever you need in here
}
```

Comment: yes but that is only good if you have only 2 groups.
What if there are more groups and more groups can be created with passage of time, Restricting them to view some controllers?
I have implemented Option 1. using `is_admin()` and `is_allowed` functions, but i want to know if its possible to apply these functions on all controllers by default?